# How to "tab" between form fields, in a table, in a protected Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm writing a macro which copies data from an Excel spreadsheet to a Word document. The Word document is protected and has legacy form fields to enter data.

I'm trying to iterate between these fields. For most of the fields, `Selection.Next(Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1).Select` works. However, some of the fields are in a table, which that solution doesn't work for.

`Selection.Next(Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1).Select` will get me into the form in the first cell of the table. But it stops there, failing to go to the next field.

I tried a number of variations, such as increasing the `Count`, and for `Unit` tried `wdParagraph`, `wdItem`, `wdCell`, `wdColumn`, `wdTable`, `wdSection`, and `wdCharacter`.  The selection stays in the first cell of the table.

I also tried `Selection.TypeText`, `Selection.NextField.Select` and `Selection.MoveDown`, which throw 4605 errors that I assume are due to document protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

`<document variable here>.FormFields(<index of form field in table>).Select`

Comment: Welcome to SO! If your code is working and solved your problem, please accept your own answer as an answer. This will help others when searching for similar questions to pick up yours, because searchers always try to look for questions that already have answers.